# test_page property at root node of CRX in AEM

Tags: aem, aem-6

Why is this node getting created after a restart of the AEM instance. i can see it in my local system. when ever i restart. once i delete it and after a restart it appears again.
[image: test_page_property]

Comment: Have you checked bundles in /install folder?

Comment: @i.net the property created on root node, may i know where to check for  /install location bundles.?

Comment: @krish the property looks like some consistency check related. not sure about the process exactly how its being get created. from your screenshot  the property has an extension of `.html` can you try [http://localhost:4502/test_page29082.html](http://localhost:4502/test_page29082.html) and see what it renders.

Comment: @VAr when i request the url [http://localhost:4502/test_page29082.html](http://localhost:4502/test_page29082.html) it renders **This is an AppScan test page** output.

Comment: crx-quickstart/install folder. Also, IIRC, I've seen instances when pen-test suites in the network are able to bypass security on OOTB AEM unsecured servers and create pages. Can you check for those as the page message looks familiar to those scenarios.